# Default null generic type

Tags: c#, generics

When i try to use `prepare("", "");` I'm getting compile error why? I set default value null what is the point compiler now.I said if i didn't put any class put there null.

> Error CS0411  The type arguments for method 'Program.prepare(string,
>   string, T)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type
>   arguments explicitly.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var person = prepare("", "");
    }

    private static Person prepare<T>(string test, string Url, T postData = null) 
        where T : class
    {
        //if postdata null do somethnig (post data can be any class it is 
         //not person class)

        //than return person
    }
}

class Person 
{
    public int age { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: The compiler can't figure out what type `T` is supposed to be.

Comment: The type `T` is necessary. `null` isn't a type, so it can't give a type to `postData`. The compiler can't choose a type for `T` from `postData`.

Comment: Maybe use `default(T)` instead of `null` as the default?

Comment: I get that this is probably a minimal example, but why is this method generic? You never use `postData`.

Comment: but i already said to compiler if i didn't put anything this need to be null

Comment: It is probabley already answered, anyway, `var person = prepare<YourType>("", "");`

Comment: This looks very much like an X/Y question - we can't tell what it should be because postData is never used.

Comment: Use method overloading instead of default parameter

Comment: you need to provide greater details about your problem. why are you using generic type and how `postData` is used inside that method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the compiler needs to know what type `T` is, even if you don´t provide it. Imagine you´re method would do anything with the provided parameter:

```
private static Person prepare<T>(string test, string Url, T postData = null) 
    where T : MyClass
{
    if(T != null) t.DoSomething();
    return new Person();
}
```

Now the **compiler** has to infer a type for `T` and thus you have to provide it - even if at **runtime** you provide `null` for the arg. That `postData` is actually `null` is a **runtime**-information, the **compiler** does not have this information - it looks solely on the *types*, not the actual *values*.

Apart from this it´s hard to suggest what you actually need. Depending on your *actual* code and what you´re doing with `postData` you may not even need generics at all.

Answer (score 4):

The desired type cannot be inferred because the argument `postData`, which is the only argument of type `T`, is optional and is not used in the incovation of the method. Furthermore, the generic function `prepare` does not use `postData`, which means that it could be removed.

Removal of the argument from the definition of `prepare` would be one solution of the problem, giving an argument of the desired type in the invoaction would be a different solution of the problem.

Answer (score 4):

> I said if i didn't put any class put there null

That's not entirely how default arguments work. They get compiled at the call site. The caller can pass `null`, but still doesn't know what "type" of null.

Given you don't provide an argument for `T postData`, the type of `T` cannot be inferred, and has to be provided explicitly.

So: `prepare<Person>("", "")`.

Answer (score 3):

The compiler error is quite clear - since any reference type can be `null`, the compiler can't infer the type from `null`.

You must specify the type like this: `var person = prepare<SomeTypeHere>("", "");`

Obviously, replace `SomeTypeHere` with the relevant type. Since it's null, and your only generic constraint is `where T : class`, you can probably just use `object`: `var person = prepare<object>("", "");`

Answer (score 1):

That error basically means that compiler cannot figure it out which type your `T` supposed to be, so you need to specify your generic type. It's usually not necessary, but in your example you are using `T` to specify type of `postData` and then, when you are trying to call your `prepare()` method, you didn't specify `postData` argument (and you can, cause it's default `null`), so compiler will not be able to know what's you `T` type:

```
var person = prepare<YourType>("", "");
```

OR

```
YourType postData = GetPostData();
var person = prepare("", "", postData);
```

Comment: person  is return class not an input

Comment: @Snr I'm not familiar with your specific task, I'm just saying that you must specify generic type of your generic method.

Answer (score 0):

As you've marked `prepare` method as generic, you must define a type. I do not see any reason for generics there.

Comment: if i put data to post i will do something else with that data.what do u mean